# Is there a list or explanation of bracket values used for TFS alert queries?

Tags: email, tfs, macros, alerts

Is there a list or explanation of bracket values used for TFS alert queries? For example: What does [Current Project] really do and what is the difference between [Me] and @Me in TFS queries?

I'm trying to get a handle on setting up TFS alerts, users are complaining they get too many useless notifications and then they don't like the fact they have to subscribe for every project they are on.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the operators and macros in alert query are same as the ones in work item query.

So you can reference the WIT query, see [Query fields, operators, and macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/query-operators-variables) for details.

For the bracket value **[Current Project]** is just the project which you involved in for now.

In Alert query, **[Me]** is just your account, that means yourself. And for the team context, the alert query interprets the **@Me** variable as **anyone who is a member of the team**.

> **Tip**: For the team context, the alert query interprets the **@Me** variable
>   as anyone who is a member of the team.
>
> ***Source here: [Set alerts, get notified when changes occur](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/alerts-and-notifications?toc=/vsts/notifications/toc.json&bc=/vsts/notifications/breadcrumb/toc.json)***

Based on your requirements, you can try to create both personal alert and team alert, or enter the eamil addresses to exclude/include the specific users  directly when create the alerts.

Comment: @Pat Delaney Have you resolved your issue by the answer above? any update?